# Uploading a string to S3 using rusoto

Tags: amazon-s3, rust, type-conversion, rusoto

I'm using [rusoto](https://github.com/rusoto/rusoto) S3 to create a JSON string and upload this string to an S3 bucket. I can create the string, but rusoto's S3 `PutObjectRequest` requires a `StreamingBody` and I'm not sure how I can create a `StreamingBody` from a string or whether this is actually necessary.

```
extern crate json;
extern crate rusoto_core;
extern crate rusoto_s3;
extern crate futures;

use rusoto_core::Region;
use rusoto_s3::{S3, S3Client, PutObjectRequest};

fn main() {
    let mut paths = Vec::new();
    paths.push(1);
    let s3_client = S3Client::new(Region::UsEast1);
    println!("{}", json::stringify(paths));
    s3_client.put_object(PutObjectRequest {
        bucket: String::from("bucket"),
        key: "@types.json".to_string(),
        body: Some(json::stringify(paths)),
        acl: Some("public-read".to_string()),
        ..Default::default()
    }).sync().expect("could not upload");
}
```

The error I get is

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:20
   |
16 |         body: Some(json::stringify(paths)),
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `rusoto_core::ByteStream`, found struct `std::string::String`
   |
   = note: expected type `rusoto_core::ByteStream`
              found type `std::string::String`
```

I'm not sure how to give this a `ByteStream`... `ByteStream::new(json::stringify(paths))` does not work and gives me a different error.

How can I upload a string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`StreamingBody`](https://docs.rs/rusoto_s3/0.36.0/rusoto_s3/type.StreamingBody.html) is a type alias:

```
type StreamingBody = ByteStream;
```

[`ByteStream`](https://docs.rs/rusoto_core/0.36.0/rusoto_core/struct.ByteStream.html) has multiple constructors, including an [implementation of `From`](https://docs.rs/rusoto_core/0.36.0/rusoto_core/struct.ByteStream.html#impl-From%3CVec%3Cu8%3E%3E):

```
impl From<Vec<u8>> for ByteStream
```

You can convert a `String` into a `Vec<u8>` using [`String::into_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes). All together:

```
fn example(s: String) -> rusoto_s3::StreamingBody {
    s.into_bytes().into()
}
```